# Manipulating an array in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a set of numeric values as an array, like so

```
100,120,0,100,90 etc
```

I also have an integer variable n

I have to count the zero's in the array, and replace the lowest non-zero (first occurence) with a zero, until the count of zero's = n

So given the data above, and an n = 3
 I would end up with

```
 0,120,0,100,0 etc
```

I need to then sum the values.

I'm not familiar with Access vba arrays, and it appears that there are not many in built array manipulation functions at all. Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Just curious, why use an array in MS Access when you have tables where this kind of thing is a doddle?

Comment: Remou - Are you referring to creating temp tables? And no the numbers canot be negative

Comment: @HansUp the array may contain any number of elements, even none

Answer (score 1):

Sort your array 
Then loop through your array starting at N to get a running total.

The thing is, you don't have to convert the lowest values to zero. All you have to do is exclude it from the summation, hence you start your running total at N (assuming 0 based array).

Reading the comments, I amended my answer to deal with empty arrays & array sizes less than N.

```
Function ArrayTotal(MyArray() As Long, N As Long)
    Dim Idx As Long
    Dim Total As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Idx = UBound(MyArray)
    If Err.Number <> 9 Then
        QuickSort1 MyArray
        If N < UBound(MyArray) Then
            For Idx = N To UBound(MyArray)
                Total = Total + MyArray(Idx)
            Next Idx
        End If
    End If
    ArrayTotal = Total
End Function

' Omit plngLeft & plngRight; they are used internally during recursion
Public Sub QuickSort1(ByRef pvarArray As Variant, Optional ByVal plngLeft As Long, Optional ByVal plngRight As Long)
    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim varSwap As Variant

    If plngRight = 0 Then
        plngLeft = LBound(pvarArray)
        plngRight = UBound(pvarArray)
    End If
    lngFirst = plngLeft
    lngLast = plngRight
    varMid = pvarArray((plngLeft + plngRight) \ 2)
    Do
        Do While pvarArray(lngFirst) < varMid And lngFirst < plngRight
            lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
        Loop
        Do While varMid < pvarArray(lngLast) And lngLast > plngLeft
            lngLast = lngLast - 1
        Loop
        If lngFirst <= lngLast Then
            varSwap = pvarArray(lngFirst)
            pvarArray(lngFirst) = pvarArray(lngLast)
            pvarArray(lngLast) = varSwap
            lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
            lngLast = lngLast - 1
        End If
    Loop Until lngFirst > lngLast
    If plngLeft < lngLast Then QuickSort1 pvarArray, plngLeft, lngLast
    If lngFirst < plngRight Then QuickSort1 pvarArray, lngFirst, plngRight
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure. I found this example of testing when the array is empty. Added it when I saw in the comments that the array may be empty.

Comment: You're right. Idx = UBound(MyArray) should be after If Err.Number...
I didn't test this code with an empty array.

Comment: I've been working on a big project and haven't had much time to get on here. I tested and corrected the code this morning.
You were right. I have no idea why the person I copied the err test line from was testing against 0, which means no error. I should have spotted that right away. Code should work now.